# When did 'going to ...' replace 'will ...' in the future tense in colloquial usage

Tags: verbs

The future tense in standard written English uses 'will' as the verbal modifier, but increasingly English speakers use 'going to' as the verbal modifier. When did this come into common usage?

Comment: See [this question: "going to" vs "will"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will). No history provided, mind you, but definitely related.

Comment: It didn't replace it; it's just a different construction. And neither one of them is the future tense; English doesn't have a future tense.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. On reflection I think what brought it to my attention was that I hear even educated people saying 'gonna' instead of 'going to'. And you are right that English has no specific future tense, just constructions that imply future intentions or predictions or hopes.

Comment: @Susan 'J'aimerais' isn't the future tense, it is the conditional - 'I would love'. I think you perhaps meant 'J'aimerai'.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Thank you. I also spelled *true* as *tru*. I'll just remove.

Answer (score 1):

'I am going to swim the English Channel' is a way of expressing a future intention in English. And whether we call it a 'future tense' or not 'I will swim the English Channel' is the more direct way of saying almost exactly the same thing about one's future plans.

This corresponds with an almost identical situation in French. And I am wondering if that is the origin of the English form.

'Je vais nager à travers la Manche' literally means 'I am going to swim the English Channel'.

'Je nagerai à travers la Manche' literally means 'I will swim the English Channel'.

The English use of 'going' in this way is confirmed by the OED as meaning V 47 b, of the verb 'go'. No etymology of this use is given except that it is compared to the French equivalent as i have done above.

Comment: @Susan. Don't apologise, the fault was mutual, once again proving that great minds think alike. I did manage to find the OED entry on that particular meaning, which I have appended to my answer. But a shame not to have found the etymology.

Answer (score 1):

In French (please let's not start a ruckus over my French like last time), as young children, we learn an easy future construction *Je vais* (I am going) plus an infinitive (say, *aimer*, to like/love) as a simple way to construct a future tense. *J'aimerai* is a bit harder.

It's reallyvery similar to learning English as children. Children learn *-ed* is a past tense for every verb. (I dropped, I wanted, I *runned*), at which point they learn irregular verbs, etc. through repeated exposure. My mother never sat me down and stated, "Today you will learn to conjugate *run*. *I* run, *you* run, *he/she/it* **runs**..." Children keep it simple until they know better. It's the *weak conjugation* first.

Perhaps that is when *I'm going to (verb)* (short: I'm gonna) came into our language - with the Norman Conquest of 1066.

**Go** appeared before the conquest (before 900; Middle English gon, Old English gān), [**going**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/going?s=t) ~1250–1300; the -ing construction is Middle English (-ing, -inge ; the variant -in). I don't have an OED susbscription, nor the expertise of linguists, so I should stop here.

Comment: +1 We have ended up answering in exactly the same way, but never mind. Whether it originates from Norman French or is a more recent import I have no idea. The OED might tell us but it might take a bit of searching through the copious meanings of 'go'.