# Difference between "will now be" and "is going to be"

Tags: verbs, future, passive-voice

What is the difference between "will now be" and "is going to be"?

Just to provide you some contest:

> The memory will now be deallocated.

vs.

> The memory is going to be deallocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, `will` and `be going to` mean the same thing. But the latter implies more certainty. But that shouldn't bother you. Regarding your question, the main difference is `now`.

When you say `The memory will now be deallocated.`, you mean the the memory is being deallocated at this moment of speaking.

`The memory is going to be deallocated.` only implies that the memory is going to be deallocated some point in the future but does not specify exact time.

`The memory will now be deallocated.` can also be expressed as `The memory is going to be deallocated now.`

See more on the difference between `will` and `going to` [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will).