# What's the difference between will and going to?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, speech

I have no idea what the difference between these are. I have heard that they have the same meaning, but how do they?

Comment: This is sort of a big thing. Can you narrow down with examples? Do you mean syntactically? Semantically? Connotations? Frequency/register?

Comment: Try reading http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Future_Will_vs_Going.htm

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You might want to take a look a these similiar posts on ["going to vs. will"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will).

Comment: Well, from what I understood, they have the same meaning, except that "going to" is planned

Comment: No, there is no "planning" aspect here. However, we may be straying into deontic modes versus epistemic ones.