# Future usage of "will" and "be going to"

Tags: future

I need some clarification about the future using "will" and "be going to".

Please, describe which variant sounds as a plan, that I planned in advance and it will definitely happen.

1. I'm going to move in America to permanent residence.
2. I'll go to London in September.

As I understand, 1) is sounds like a plan for the future, that may be happen, but it's not clear yet.
And the point 2) sounds like that will happen definitely.

Am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will

Comment: That's right. _Will_ is for things that are scheduled or generally expected to happen in the future. _Going to_ is for things that appear likely to happen, possibly soon. Note that _Watch out!_ can be followed by _That rock is going to fall!_ but not *_That rock will fall!_

Comment: @marcellothearcane I'll look into it right now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnLawler huh, as I understand it, this case is used when you are sure that something will happen based on the situation that is going right now, isn't it?

Comment: In your example there's pretty much no difference.

Comment: @JohnLawler Really? the only difference I understand is that 'will' is more formal and less common, no sense of likelihood.

Comment: I'd only expect 'I'll go to London in September.' as a statement of resolve or  a decision actually being made at this moment. To express modality (here, belief in a high probability), I'd use 'I'm definitely going to move to America to live there.'

Comment: What I described above is American usage, btw. The examples are from Bob Binnick's 1971 paper in CLS 7. There has been lots of work since; [here's a bibliography.](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0075424203257830)