# What is the grammatical problem with this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I need to leave early because I will meet a friend for lunch.

The above sentence is not grammatically correct but I cannot tell exactly what the problem is. Is it the usage of 'will'?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct? (I can't see anything wrong, myself.)

Comment: Actually it is one of the questions of a grammar task. I find it hard to tell the problem so I raised the question.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing at all wrong with it grammatically.

It's not quite idiomatic because of the "will": it would be more natural with "I am going to meet" or "I am meeting", as those are more often used when there is a definite intention.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really ungrammatical, but it's rather odd.  The reason for your leaving early must have to do with when your lunch meeting is scheduled, but the sentence doesn't really say that.  Maybe this would be better: "... because of a lunch date with a friend."

Answer (score 1):

"I need to leave early because I will meet a friend for lunch."

Should be:

"I need to leave early because I will be meeting a friend for lunch."

The first sentence is discordant in its use of tense. However, depending on context, it is technically grammatically correct - if someone were expressing resolve "Yes, I will meet a friend for lunch!" The person has no specific plans, but they are affirming their intention. This was used frequently with Jason Alexander's character George Costanza on Seinfeld.