# 1st conditional: will / going to

Tags: conditionals

I have read that even though it is the not the most common structure, we can use "be going to + infinitive" in the first conditional. Is there a difference in the meaning of these sentences?:

- If it stops raining, I'm going to walk into town.
- If it stops raining, I will walk into town.

Comment: Hello, Alfrrread. This question would be better asked on ELL, our sister site, but like us they'd expect at least a bit of research to have been done and added. // The second sentence sounds formal without the usual contraction (_I'll_), and would probably only be used in normal conversation where one was contrasting walking into town with say driving there (ie emphasising _walk_).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["going to" vs "will"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will)

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth ... "First conditional" is a concept from ESL, so you are more likely to find people who know what it means at ELL.

Comment: There's also the emphatic usage: "If it stops raining, I _will_ walk into town! Try and stop me!"

Comment: **Note**: I voted to close this as a duplicate. (See the comments.) I definitely *don't* believe that this is not about the English language. (It is.)

Answer (score -4):

If it stops raining, I'm going to walk into town. = you have planned your walking into town but somehow it rained and you have to cancel this. But you might tell you friend like your #1.

if it stops raining, I will walk into town. = it rained, and I do not think I need or I want to go to walk into town, but if it stops raining, I will walk into town and it is just an action in time, I did not plan to walk into town before.

Comment: I don't see that distinction myself. 'I will walk into town' does not carry any implication that the intention did not exist before.

Comment: Really sorry if my explanation is not good enough. You can check the book " The English Verb" written by Michael Lewis. He explained "will" is the word shown the immediate plan, act means did not plan anything before, like " will take the phone" .. ..

Comment: So why do all the web pages about English conditionals use *will* and not mention this distinction? For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) gives the example *"If it rains, the picnic will be canceled,"* which clearly should be *going to* according to your answer, but sounds perfectly fine to me as a native speaker of English. Are they all wrong?

Comment: @PeterShor you can recheck the definition of will. Will is the word shown the strong possibility and willingness to do or to happen something. As your example, its obvious nobody would plan it before, I mean the rain, but if it rains, 100% the picnic cancels. Wiki is not wrong, just the aspect of language. Michael Lewis is the master of English language. You might read his book for further knowledge.

Comment: Does Michael Lewis discuss when to use *will* and when to use *going to* in the context of the first conditional in his book?

Comment: @PeterShor if you are curious about that, you could check it yourself. Or you can choose to believe in yourself, which make you feel better. Nice day.