# Will vs going to with a personal skill

Tags: tenses, future

Lately, we had our finals and a question popped up in that went like this:

Liverpool players are known to be skilled. They ...... The match easily.
The choices were: "will win" or "are going to win"

Lots of people are debating because some consider "known to be skilled" and "easily" as evidences. So, it should be "are going to".
And others say that the personal skills are not evidences. So, it's "will win".

Sorry for my long intro, but hope I find a final answer here.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: There is a large intermediate ground between the extreme cases where it's clear which of *are going to* and *will* you should use, and where native speakers can use either one. This falls into it. If your teachers gave you the impression that for every sentence in English, only one of these verbs works, they gave you the wrong impression.

Comment: And if they will accept only one answer for this question on the test, it's a badly written test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["going to" vs "will"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will) as asked over 6 years ago. And **EXACTLY** the same question (same example sentence) was asked only 2 days ago.